# Why is this temporary table throwing an error about the number of column supplied?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to run this specific code for a temp table, but somehow I get this error

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

What's wrong?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #GamesDistribution

CREATE TABLE #GamesDistribution 
(
    Platform nvarchar(255),
    Name nvarchar(255),
    NA_Sales numeric,
    EU_Sales numeric,
    JP_Sales numeric
)

INSERT INTO #GamesDistribution
    SELECT 
        properties.Platform,
        properties.Name,
        revenue.NA_Sales,
        revenue.EU_Sales,
        revenue.JP_Sales
    FROM 
        games_properties AS Properties
    JOIN 
        games_revenue AS Revenue ON properties.Game_ID = Revenue.Game_ID
    --GROUP BY properties.platform
    --ORDER BY Total_Games DESC, Total_NA_Sales DESC, Total_EU_Sales DESC, Total_JP_Sales DESC;
```

Comment: I suspect there is something we aren't being told here. Have you tried actually specifying the columns in your `INSERT` clause? YOu *should* be doing that anyway.

Comment: Have you, by any chance, created the table `#GamesDistribution` in the session previously? IF so, that definition will be checked for the `INSERT` as it's in the same batch.

Comment: No, I haven't created it before, I even added the `DROP TABLE IF EXIST` to prevent that. And if I'm not wrong, the columns are being called correctly, no? @Larnu

Comment: If the table already exists, it doesn't matter if you use `DROP IF EXISTS` first; the `INSERT` in the batch will be checked against the *current* definition of the table. If you put a `GO` prior to the `INSERT` I *bet* the problem disappears.

Comment: Guess what? You were right, lol. Care to explain why `DROP IF EXISTS` doesn't work before the `INSERT` clause? I even saw a video on YouTube where the guy didn't use `GO` and worked for him. And thanks, by the way, you're a savor.

Comment: The problem is the parsing; the statement is never run because the statements didn't compile.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that prior to you running your batch the table already exists. As such when the batch is parsed, by the compiler, the compilation fails; because the number of columns doesn't match that of the table already exists.

This can be replicated with the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #t (I int);

INSERT INTO #t (I)
VALUES(1);

GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;
CREATE TABLE #t (I int, D date);

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES(2,GETDATE());
GO

SELECT *
FROM #t;
GO
DROP TABLE #t
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea2a6235165910ef767e11f6dd3a3da4)

This returns the error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

And the dataset:

| I |
| --- |
| 1 |

This is because the 2nd batch, with the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` *never* ran; the compilation failed.

The "simple" solution here would be to put your `DROP IF EXISTS` in a separate batch, and also specify your columns:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #GamesDistribution;
GO
CREATE TABLE #GamesDistribution (Platform nvarchar(255),
                                 Name nvarchar(255),
                                 NA_Sales numeric,  --Where is your precision and scale?
                                 EU_Sales numeric,  --Where is your precision and scale?
                                 JP_Sales numeric); --Where is your precision and scale?

INSERT INTO #GamesDistribution (Platform,Name, NA_Sales,EU_Sales,JP_Sales)
SELECT properties.Platform,
        properties.Name,
        revenue.NA_Sales,
        revenue.EU_Sales,
        revenue.JP_Sales
FROM dbo.games_properties AS Properties
     JOIN dbo.games_revenue AS Revenue ON properties.Game_ID = Revenue.Game_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this way

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #GamesDistribution

SELECT properties.Platform,
        properties.Name,
        revenue.NA_Sales,
        revenue.EU_Sales,
        revenue.JP_Sales
INTO #GamesDistribution
FROM games_properties AS Properties
JOIN games_revenue AS Revenue
    ON properties.Game_ID = Revenue.Game_ID
```

and then you can check the columns' data types of the temp table:

```
EXEC tempdb..sp_help '#GamesDistribution'

SELECT * 
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GamesDistribution');
```

*Note*: It's always better to ensure the columns' data types. Your query might list different columns' data types.

Answer (score 1):

Add **GO** statement under drop table as below.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #GamesDistribution
GO

CREATE TABLE #GamesDistribution 
( 
.
.
.
```